# With mstest, can I run my unit test suite against each of my supported languages?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, internationalization, continuous-integration, mstest

We use .resx files to internationalize our app to several languages. Our automated unit tests are in their own assembly, and we run mstest on that project from the command line from within our CI (Jenkins) like this:

> mstest.exe /testcontainer:unittests.dll /category:"!TemporaryExclude" /resultsfile:UnitTests.trx

We've found cases where particular unit tests would fail if run on a machine set to one of our non-English supported cultures. We'd like to have our CI run the unit tests against each culture, including the current en-us one. This must be a problem that other people have run into, but I haven't found anything on it.

**Is there a way to run mstest against a specific culture?** I didn't see anything in [the command-line docs for mstest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I know that I could specify the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture in my tests, but I don't want devs on our team to have to copy-paste duplicates of their tests, one per culture. It would be extra work for them and having duplicates different only by culture would be hard to maintain and prone to errors.

I wondered about deriving a class from TestMethodAttribute and having it cycle through all my language resource DLLs, running the test code once for each, but Visual Studio tells me:

> Error 2   'ClassToExtendTestMethodAttribute':
>   cannot derive from sealed type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestMethodAttribute'

Same for TestClassAttribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea might be to read the culture from a config file in the `TestInitialize` method in order to use with `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, and putting this method into a base unit test class (that all other test classes should be deriving from). 
If this does the trick, you can call `mstest` from a batch file in a loop and change the config file (from "en-us" to "fr-FR" for example) after every step.

Alternatively, here is a pointer to a "[Unit Test Extensibility Sample](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/UnitTestExtendSample)" which I haven't used, but might help you.

Comment: +1 Great idea! I'd rather not do the same the file access before executing each test (given the number of tests we have) so I'm going to try ClassInitialize instead of TestInitialize. If I get that working, I'll still accept your answer.

Comment: @heginy It looks like derived classes don't execute their parent's ClassInitialize unless they explicitly call it from a ClassInitialize method of their own. Derived classes *do* execute their parent's TestInitialize, so I could get your technique to work that way. As I said, I wouldn't be thrilled about making every test go out to the file system. I'll probably choose the ClassInitialize technique, even though there's the one extra step besides subclassing. Accepting your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffH Great, glad that it worked. You're right about the file access each time. If you can solve it with ClassInitialize, maybe AssemblyInitialize could work too.

Comment: @heginy It gets more interesting now that I'm using the MSTest Jenkins plugin to browse results. ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin ) That plugin takes exactly one .trx file and displays a trend chart and allows drilldown. I can't combine the runs into one, so which test run's results am I going to use? My default culture? One of the other languages that sometimes cause unit test failures? Do I write custom logic to force Jenkins to display data for the run with the most (if any) failures? I'm still surprised nobody else seems to have this concern.

Comment: @JeffH Yeah, one thinks it should be a more common concern. I'm wondering if people are running separate VM's set for each culture, but that might mean a separate CI server per culture (maybe certain CI servers support multiple testbeds?). All in all a challenge... Lastly, I definitely recommend testing out for Turkish (if it's in your targets), based on experience:)